# Should I be concerned about plagiarism with this excerpt in a research paper?

Tags: academic-writing, citations, plagiarism

I'm new to writing research papers and I need some help, with plagiarism in general. Here is an excerpt from my paper. Is this within the usual norms for research papers, or am I risking plagiarizing?

*“Clay has the general theoretical formula Al2O3 2SiO2 2H20 There are numberless varieties of clay, but it may roughly be divided into ball clay, china clay, and fire clay; or, in other words, a plastic clay, a non-plastic clay, and a refractory clay.” (Stephenson 12)*

Here's a link to a pdf of the text. [Ceramic Chemistry by. H.H. Stephenson](https://ia800302.us.archive.org/12/items/ost-chemistry-ceramic_chemistry/Ceramic_chemistry.pdf)

Comment: It seems like you're doing fine to me. If you are quoting longer than a sentence, you may wish to use a block quote or say *Stephenson writes: "Clay has the theoretical ..." (Stevenson, 12)*

Comment: Welcome to Writers.  I've made some edits to your question and clarified the title; if I've misunderstood anything, please feel free to [edit] further.  I also added the academic-writing tag; I'm assuming this paper is for academia or a class assignment?  If not, we can remove or change that tag.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**For research, refer to AMA Style. If it's not your words, idea or IP - *attribute*!**
Looks like you are doing ok so far.